# Asynchronous call of inprocess COM-DLL from VSTO Excel Addin?

Tags: excel, com, asynchronous, vsto, add-in

I am developing an application level VSTO 4 Addin for Microsoft Excel 2007 / 2010. 
The result is a windows forms based DLL using .Net 4 Client Profile.

Now I have to use a legacy COM-DLL. It is no problem to set the reference and access the COM-Methods via COM-Interop from .Net.

But the the (synchronous) method I need to call can take a minute or longer to get back.

I know your answer: 
Use a worker thread...

I **have** used The Task Parallel Library to put the long lasting operation in a worker task and keep the GUI (Excel) responding.

---

But: The inprocess COM-Call (in the worker task/thread) still seems to **block** my GUI-Thread.

- Why? Is it because Excel is always running as STA (Single Thread
  Apartment)?
- How can I keep the Excel GUI responding?
- Is there a way to make it really asynchronous?

---

Thanks for any answers,

Jörg

Comment: I don't think there's a real solution. See [All Outlook object model calls run on the main thread](http://weblogs.asp.net/whaggard/archive/2008/02/04/all-outlook-object-model-calls-run-on-the-main-thread.aspx) and [Is ApplicationClass Thread Safe?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsto/thread/a4775ced-fa6d-44bf-b039-5bc72188e823)

Comment: These are good links. So the answer is 'Yes - Excel is always running as STA'. This indeed makes asynchronous work tricky to implement.

Comment: I am facing a very similar issue...did you find an answer ?

Comment: Not really. I am blocking the Excel GUI and show a ProgressBar form which I can keep on moving by ugly Sleep / DoEvents. But the blocking synchron call to my legacy COM-DLL (in a worker thread) still cannot be interrupted. Not even if I use (the even more ugly) TerminateThread or a WorkerThread.Abort. I have made some experiments using a .NET WCF Server Component to host to legacy COM-DLL. This would be the cleanest way I think but there is one more component in the game then...

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've found an answer to this topic:

I've readed a lot about COM Threading Models and then spoke to the developer of the COM-DLL I am calling as an InProc-Server.

Together we changed the [threading model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model#Threading) of the COM-DLL:

- OLD (blocking): Single-Threaded Apartment (STA), (ThreadingModel=Apartment)
- **NEW (working): Multi-Threaded Apartment (MTA), (ThreadingModel=Free)**

Since we have our own synchronization mechanisms in the COM-DLL, there are no problems caused by the missing synchronization via the standard Windows message queue.

Problem was, that even the UI Thread was idle and even if it did [DoEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents(v=vs.110).aspx), the important windows messages ([WM_Paint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145213(v=vs.85).aspx), etc.) were not delivered.

Now they are. The UI is responding at every time and the call to the COM-DLL is still done in a worker thread (as mentioned above, it's a [ThreadPool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.threading.threadpool(v=vs.110).aspx) thread which is used by the [Task Parallel Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx)).